# On closing one tab all the tabs are being closed in reactjs where I add tabs dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 2 problems, firstly On clicking add button, 2 same tabs are being opened. Secondly on closing the tab all the tabs are being closed and shows this error that I have attached in the image. I have problem with closing the tab. I want to close a particular tab that I close instead of closing all tabs. please look into this problem.

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Tabs, Button } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.newTabIndex = 0;
    const panes = [
     
    ];

    this.state = {
      activeKey: 0,
      panes,
    };
    
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onEdit = this.onEdit.bind(this);
    this.add = this.add.bind(this);
    this.remove = this.remove.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(activeKey) {
    this.setState({ activeKey });
    console.log(activeKey);
  };

  onEdit(targetKey, action){
    this[action](targetKey);
  };

  add = targetKey => {
    console.log('targetKey', targetKey)
      let { activeKey } = this.state;
      //if (targetKey !== activeKey){
        this.setState(prevState => { 
          const newState = {...prevState};
          newState.panes.push({title:'Tab '+ targetKey, content:'Content of tab pane '+ targetKey,key: activeKey+1});
          return newState;
          });
      //}
    };

    remove = targetKey => {
      let { activeKey } = this.state;
      let lastIndex;
      this.setState(prevState => { 
          const newState = {...prevState};
          newState.forEach((pane, i) => {
              if (pane.key === targetKey) {
                lastIndex = i - 1;
              }
          });
          const panes = newState.filter(pane => pane.key !== targetKey);
          if (panes.length && activeKey === targetKey) {
              if (lastIndex >= 0) {
                activeKey = panes[lastIndex].key;
              } else {
                activeKey = panes[0].key;
              }
          }
          return ({panes, activeKey});
      });  
    };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="tab-section">
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
          {
            ['1', '2', '3'].map(item => 
              <Button key={item} onClick={() => this.add(item)}>ADD Tab-{item}</Button>
            )
          }

        </div>
        <Tabs
          hideAdd
          onChange={this.onChange}
          activeKey={this.state.activeKey}
          type="editable-card"
          onEdit={this.onEdit}
        >
          {this.state.panes.map(pane => (
            <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
              {pane.content}
            </TabPane>
          ))}
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


export default App;
```

Snaps of the outputs:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/m55Bx.png

Initially panes were defined this way, which shows the tabs even before button click. But my actual requirement is tabs should pop-up on button click. So I have removed the panes made it empty.

```
{ title: 'Tab 1', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 1', key: '1' },
{ title: 'Tab 2', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 2', key: '2' },
{ title: 'Tab 3', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 3', key: '3' },
```

Note- "antd": "^4.16.13" "react": "^17.0.2", "react-dom": "^17.0.2", "react-scripts": "4.0.3", are the packages used.

Comment: change `newState` to `newState.panes` to run `forEach` & `filter`

Comment: I have a new error -TypeError: newState.filter is not a function

Comment: > 57 | const panes = newState.filter(pane => pane.key !== targetKey);
     | ^  58 | if (panes.length && activeKey === targetKey) {
  59 |     if (lastIndex >= 0) {
  60 |       activeKey = panes[lastIndex].key;

Comment: `newState.filter` -> `newState.panes.filter`

Comment: Yes I have changed the as well, there is no error. But there is no change while closing the tab. Tabs are not closing.

Comment: What if I change the line 16 to - activeKey: panes[0].key,?

Comment: `add` function uses `activeKey + 1`, so if you add a new pane, it may add a pane with the same key. Causes two panes to be opened.

Comment: Are there only 3 panes?

Comment: No, it would be dynamic, according to number of option in the navbar.

Comment: You need to add a new state to record the key of last pane.

Comment: Could you please help me in making this work. I hope you got the question, I need to add the particular tab on clicking the button and I need to close the particular one on closing the tab. if the tab is already opened, it should'nt open again.

Comment: Let me confirm again, `add` will add new pane information with `targetKey`, and `remove` will delete all panes with `targetKey`?

Comment: Yes, add should add a new pane, remove should delete only the particular pane, not all the panes. Please use this-https://jsfiddle.net/yjumr4ox/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored the code (https://jsfiddle.net/6719phr3/1/):

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      focusingPaneKey: '',
      openingPaneKeys: [],
    }
  }

  openPane = (paneKey) => {
    this.setState(({ ...state }) => {
      if (!state.openingPaneKeys.includes(paneKey)) {
        state.openingPaneKeys = [...state.openingPaneKeys, paneKey]
      }

      state.focusingPaneKey = paneKey
      return state
    })
  }

  closePane = (paneKey) => {
    this.setState(({ ...state }) => {
      if (paneKey === state.focusingPaneKey) {
        const paneKeyIndex = state.openingPaneKeys.indexOf(paneKey)
        state.focusingPaneKey = state.openingPaneKeys[paneKeyIndex - 1]
      }

      state.openingPaneKeys = state.openingPaneKeys.filter((openingPaneKey) => openingPaneKey !== paneKey)

      return state
    })
  }

  handleTabsEdit = (key, action) => {
    if (action === 'remove') {
      this.closePane(key)
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { panes } = this.props
    const keysOfPane = Object.keys(panes)

    return (
      <div className="tab-section">
        <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
          {keysOfPane.map((key) => (
            <Button key={key} onClick={() => this.openPane(key)}>
              ADD Tab-{key}
            </Button>
          ))}
        </div>
        <Tabs
          hideAdd
          onChange={this.openPane}
          activeKey={this.state.focusingPaneKey}
          type="editable-card"
          onEdit={this.handleTabsEdit}
        >
          {this.state.openingPaneKeys
            .map((key) => panes[key])
            .map((pane) => (
              <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
                {pane.content}
              </TabPane>
            ))}
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

You can pass panes data by props.

Comment: Yessss.... will this work for any number of buttons and panes.?

Comment: Wait, I found some bugs, the fixed version has been updated

Comment: Yes, this will work for any number of buttons & panes.

Comment: I do have one doubt if the tab is already open, it should'nt open again instead pop the already opened tab.

Comment: Do you mean that the new pane will open when `add` is called?

Comment: If Add Tab-1 is already opened, if we click it again instead adding a new tab, the opened tab should be the active tab. Lets take For example in vs code a file is opened, if we open it again then it wont pop up in new tab right, what it does is it pops up already opened tab.

Comment: Oh, ok, I got it.

Comment: Done, new code has been updated. You can pass panes data by props.